# When do widget class names end with "View" vs. "Layout" vs. neither?

Tags: android, naming-conventions, naming

Is there a pattern or naming convention for if an Android widget class name should end with "View", "Layout", or neither?

Comment: There is no official naming system. Roughly speaking, if a `ViewGroup` is a layout manager, doing the same sorts of things as does `LinearLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, and kin, then having the class name end in `Layout` is reasonable. Beyond that, use whatever suits you.

Answer (score 2):

If the class extends View (or extends View in it's hierarchy), then it should end with "View", for example "TextView", or "ImageView".
These views can't contain other views inside them.

If the class extends a ViewGroup (or extends ViewGroup in its hierarchy), then it should end with "Layout", for example "RelativeLayout", "FrameLayout".
These views CAN contain other views inside them.

Comment: That does not explain classes that do not end in either `View` or `Layout`. Your first rule also fails for `ListView`, `GridView`, and `RecyclerView`, as they have children but end in `View`.

Comment: I'm not sure that having `View` in the hierarchy leads to consistent naming in the Android API: `AutoCompleteTextView ` extends `EditText`, so the word `View` is omitted in the parent class name (EditText) and then re-added (as opposed to `AutoCompleteEditText`).

Confusingly, `ScrollView` extends `FrameLayout` even though it is `ViewGroup` (and is not instead called `ScrollableLayout` or something like that.)

Answer (score 1):

All android UI components are a child of the **View** base class.

Out of **View** cildrens you can have **ViewGroups** and **Widgets**.

**ViewGroups**: Can contain other views or viewgroups inside of them to create complex UI's. some examples of ViewGroups are: FrameLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout and others.

**Widgets**: Ui components with a specific purpose and don't contain other Widgets or View groups inside of them. Example of widgets are TextViews, Buttons, etc.

Answering to your question a good rule of thumb is to identify if what you are building or modifying will fall under one of the two categories above and if it falls under the **ViewGroup** use the class name followed by the **Layout** (example**MyXYZLayout**) word and if it is a widget give it a name followed by the **View**(example:**MyXYZView** word.

I would advise you to look at some open source projects and see how are they naming their custom Views so that you can have a sense and develop some heuristics on how to do this.

Ultimately it is going to be up to your team to define the conventions of how to do this in the right way that makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

That's how Google has decided it. There is an [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and [Button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) while both are extending [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).